# Show changes in footer and pagernumbering for different revisions of a document

Tags: revision-control

Let's say I have a 10 page technical document. On pages 5 and 6 I include a 2 page external pdf. Later I make changes and the 2 page external pdf becomes bigger and now has three pages. I need to keep track about this change by

- first making sure that on page 5 and 6 I add a revision letter A in the footer and
- secondly by giving the third external pdf page the pagenumber 6.1 and the revision letter A in the footer.
- the old 7th page should still have the page number 7 even though technically speaking it would be then the 8th page.

If it is the second change of the document, the revision letter should be B, third change C, etc...

To make things more complicated if I make changes in the original tex file, these changes should also be reflected with the addition of a revision letter in the footer. And now comes the crux. All the other pages shall stay the same. Let's say I add two lines of text on page 2, so some of the text on page 2 gets pushed into page 3. The pages 2 and 3 should then get a revision letter, but page 4,5,.. should stay untouched. That means no suddenly appearing figures of page 3 on page 4. At least not outside of subsections. If a new page is necessary it should have the pagenumber 3.1 for example.

Are there any existing packages that can do that? If it helps, using git to version control the tex file is an option.

Comment: You can use `\setcounter{page}{7}` and even `\renewcommand{\thepage}{6A}` or `\renewcommand{\thepage}{6\Alph{page}}` temporarily.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for the Ideas. Was hoping for an automatic approach without doing to much manual tinkering. But this could work as plan B.

Comment: The easy solution would be to simply let the pages get renumbered.  Only slide shows use subpages.